# RandomAccessFile doesn't work with Minecraft Forge

Tags: java, networking, minecraft, named-pipes, minecraft-forge

I'm working at the moment on a Mod for Minecraft with a dedicated Gui system written in C++ and Qt5. I let my GUI and Minecraft communicate through a named pipe, but I have there a small problem. I can read and write with a simple Java and C++(Qt) program into the pipe. But when I create a new instance of my Pipeendpoint class in post init of Minecraft Forge it can't read anything from the Pipe. In a standalone system, it can read stuff.

Not working Forge Implementation:

```
package de.CoderDE.CodersAnimationEditor;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import de.CoderDE.CodersAnimationEditor.Pipe.PipeEndpoint;
import net.minecraft.client.Minecraft;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.client.registry.ClientRegistry;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.event.FMLInitializationEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.event.FMLPostInitializationEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.event.FMLPreInitializationEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.relauncher.Side;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.relauncher.SideOnly;

@SideOnly(Side.CLIENT)
public class ClientProxy extends CommonProxy {
    static PipeEndpoint pendpoint;

    @Override
    public void preInit(FMLPreInitializationEvent e) {
        super.preInit(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FMLInitializationEvent e) {
        super.init(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void postInit(FMLPostInitializationEvent e) {
        super.postInit(e);

        try {
            pendpoint = new PipeEndpoint();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Working standalone implementation:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import de.CoderDE.CodersAnimationEditor.Pipe.PipeEndpoint;


public class Main {
    static PipeEndpoint pipe;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            pipe = new PipeEndpoint();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And the important PipeEndpoint class:

```
package de.CoderDE.CodersAnimationEditor.Pipe;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;

public class PipeEndpoint {
    private Thread reciever;
    private RandomAccessFile pipe;

    public PipeEndpoint() throws FileNotFoundException {
        pipe = new RandomAccessFile("\\\\.\\pipe\\CodersAnimationEditor", "rw");
        reciever = new Thread(new PipeEndpointReciever());
        reciever.start();
    }

    private class PipeEndpointReciever implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    System.out.print((char)pipe.read());
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And with "can't read anything" I mean that it never returns from pipe.read().
Oh, and the Java application starts after the C++(Qt) LocalServer started listening and waits for a new connection.

Comment: You should never call `Thread.sleep` on the minecraft main thread. While not causing your problem, it is not good.

Comment: That is only for testing purposes there, in the real mod there is no sleep ^^

Comment: I figured, but it was worth throwing up a yellow warning flag.